# Can I upgrade my laptop's battery with one with a higher voltage to make my laptop last longer?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an ASUS Zenbook Flip S (UX370UA) and its battery is 5070 mAh, and 7.7v which equals to 39 Wh.

Needless to say, this battery allows my laptop to last about 2.5 hours which is pretty bad.

Is there a way to get a battery that would make my laptop last longer? If so, does anyone have a link for such a battery?

Comment: Higher voltage is a bad idea. Higher mha is a way to do it. Not sure if it exists, but a way to do it. I had a laptop with a third part battery sticking out an inch or so on the back of the computer

Answer (score 0):

You cant squeeze a larger battery in to the same physical space (and if you could you would not want a higher voltage battery - higher (milli)amp hours@
7.7 volt is what is required.)

2.5 hours is very low for that laptop (manufactuers talk about 11 hours) - unless you are doing heavy gaming it should last longer  then 2.5 hours.  This likely means either the battery is faulty or there is  a software issue draining the battery or both. Look to see resource use and diagnose if its doing a lot when idle to check software, and charge it, then unplug and leave it overnight to check for significant self discharge which likely shows battery failure.

If none of the above helps you can - with a lot of effort - find external battery banks which support USB-C PD - it might be worth looking at one. Maybe something like [https://www.amazon.com/Portable-RAVPower-20100mAh-Delivery-External/dp/B07KS5Z8GL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KS5Z8GL)